# How to send value from JavascriptInterface method to Oncreate method?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am taking value from webview using JavascriptInterface. I recieve this value alright in JavascriptInterface method.
 But i want this value at Oncreate method. How to do this?
This is my java code.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String check(String p) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return p;
}
```

I want result "p" in Oncreate method. But when I call Toast at Oncreate method it gives a null value, why?

Comment: put all code the oncreate and this method to better help

Comment: @BrunoFerreira, Didn't understand what you mean?